# Define a `globalThis` symbol index type definition

Tags: typescript

Through the `typings/global.d.ts` I can define a type through `declare module global { }`. However, I am unaware how I would be able to define a `symbol` index through this syntax.

Imagine the following code, which does compile in JavaScript, but complains in strict TS ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/OYGw9gRghiAqAWBLAzgbQMoE8C2EwgDoAzMAJwAoByRAOwBcBTUmmYqAawcoEoBdAAgC8-AN79wAEyhMAXPzqkArg34BfANwBYAFA6AxmBrJ8DAuGDlQkGAhQYceQiQrV6TFk45c%203dUA)):

```
globalThis[Symbol.for('internal.fake')] = { loader: true };
console.log(globalThis[Symbol.for('internal.fake')]);
```

The following TS error can be seen:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'symbol' can't be used to index type 'typeof globalThis'.(7053)

Would it be possible to define this in a typescript friendly way, **without** having to cheat using any assertions?

Comment: Yeah, we can cheat using `never` assertions!

Comment: Node or browser?